# Is there a way to use files like cfg.py to make global variables for multi-processing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables

I am trying to read and write byte arrays in multi-processing.  Is there a way to make this method work for subprocesses?

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

because of the all the numerous lines of code to define the mp's and sockets I will try to summarize the best I can

I have tried importing the config.py in each process

```
config.py:
x = 0   # Default value of the 'x' configuration setting
y = 0

mod.py:

import config
def run_socket(socket):
    data = socket.recv(8)
    config.x = int.from_bytes(data[0:4])
    config.y = int.from_bytes(data[4:8])


main.py:

import config
import mod
import multiprocessing as mp

#define and start a socket

def run_this():
    while True:
        mod.run_socket(socket)


aprocess = mp.Process(target = run_this, args=(variables,)

# I have 4 more process that I want to update config.x and config.y in. I cannot get them to update.
```

Currently all the values stay at config.py value unless I update them inside of the run_socket function. But I need to update them in the other processes.  This is on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager).

> The `multiprocessing.Manager` returns a started `SyncManager` object which can be used for sharing objects between processes. The returned manager object corresponds to a spawned child process and has methods that will create shared objects and return corresponding proxies.

[Here's an example](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/02/19/sharing-global-variables-in-python-using-multiprocessing/)

Comment: I am glad it helped. Maybe you can accept the answer then?